# Python 3 send a request with a file using only standard libraries

Tags: python, file, http, post, python-requests

So I have the following Code which is working using the requests library:

```
file_test = {'file': ('test.json', open('C:/Users/abc/test.json','rb'), 'application/json')}

response = requests.post(url, files=file_test, verify=False)
```

which works as expected. But recently company want us to use only standard libraries. So I went ahead to try out `http.client` library to accomplish the exact same thing:

```
httpHost = 'some host'
uri = 'some uri'
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(httpHost,context = ssl._create_unverified_context())
with open('C:/Users/abc/test.json','rb') as file:
    f = file.read()
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=TESTabc123',
    'Content-Length': str(len(f)),
    'Accept' : '*/*'
}  
conn.request(verb, uri, body=f, headers=headers)
print(conn.getresponse().status)
```

However, I am hitting a 500 status code with the above code. Just to mention, the headers part I pulled the exact same thing from postman (I was able to get a 200 on postman with the same file and same headers).

Am I doing this thing correctly? It seems like I followed everything correctly but still getting undesired results. I also tried with urllib's request library but seems like the verify=False part doesn't work on there.

The only thing I can think of is the request content length, which in postman, also gives a 500 error when wrong length is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import http.client
import ssl

httpHost = 'some host'
uri = 'some uri'
boundary = 'TESTabc123'

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection(httpHost, 
context=ssl._create_unverified_context())

with open('C:/Users/abc/test.json', 'rb') as file:
    f = file.read()

body = (
    f'--{boundary}\r\n'
    f'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.json"\r\n'
    'Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n'
    f'{f.decode()}\r\n'
    f'--{boundary}--\r\n'
)

    headers = {
    'Content-Type': f'multipart/form-data; boundary={boundary}',
    'Content-Length': str(len(body)),
    'Accept': '*/*'
}

conn.request('POST', uri, body=body, headers=headers)
print(conn.getresponse().status)
```

I think this will be better

Comment: I am still getting the error (400 bad request instead of 500 now), even changing the 'Content-Length'. But I do see the idea

Comment: This ended up working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [requests documentation](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file), the Content-Length should be the number of bytes in the file, not the length of the text, could you try changing `'Content-Length': str(len(f)),` to `'Content-Length': len(f),`.
Also make sure verb = post.

Let me know if that Helps - Jack

Comment: I tried changing it to len(f) and confirmed it is using "POST", but I am still getting the 500 Error..

Comment: could you try comparing the packets on wireshark or checking the servers logs?